# Assistance needed with a regular expression

Tags: regex, wordpress, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

I have a block of content with people's names in double brackets. For example:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur [[Jane Doe]] adipisicing elit,
>   sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut
>   enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco [[John Doe]]
>   laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
>   in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
>   pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, [[Susan
>   Van-Something]] sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est
>   laborum.

I am trying to write a regular expression that takes the names out of the double brackets and replaces them in the content with a link following the formatting below:

> `<a href='http://www.example.com/jane-doe/'>Jane Doe</a>`

In the URL the spaces are transformed into hyphens and the entire name is lowercased.

So far i have

```
// the filter function
function names_brackets( $content ) {
    // regex replace the names with links
    // return the content
    return preg_replace_callback( "/^([[[A-Za-z0-9- ]+?]])/" , "names_callback" , $content);
}

// callback function to allow post processing
function names_callback ( $matches ) {
    $find = array(' ', '[', ']');
    $replace = array('-', '', '');
    return '<a href="http://www.example.com/' . strtolower( str_replace($find, $replace, $matches[1]) ) . '">' . str_replace(']', '', str_replace('[', '', $matches[1])) . '</a>';
}
```

Unfortunately I suspect that there is something wrong with the regular expression. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that your names will always consist of nothing more than ASCII letters, spaces, numbers (?) and dashes?

Comment: yes all names are letters (probably no numbers, but why not) and dashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do need to escape your brackets in the pattern, but there's still room for improvement: you actually don't have to do another search-and-replace within the callback function, if you use *several* capture groups. Like here:

```
function names_brackets( $content ) {
    return preg_replace_callback('/(\[\[)([\w -]+?)(]])/',
               'names_callback', $content);
}

function names_callback ( $matches ) {
    return '<a href="http://www.example.com/' 
           . strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $matches[2])) 
           . "\">$matches[2]</a>";
}
```

This way both opening and closing brackets will still be cut out from the result, but the callback function won't even have to know about them: it only uses the second group - the one with the name.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the literal brackets and remove the start-of-string anchor:

```
"/(\[\[[A-Za-z0-9 -]+\]\])/"
```

Comment: Ah, you got there just a second or two before me. Schucks!

Comment: still get nothing :( it is part of a wordpress filter the first line that calls the names_brackets function is:

add_filter( 'the_content', 'names_brackets' );

Comment: @user1898568: Indeed, I had overlooked the `^` in your regex which ties the match to the beginning of the string. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern is a bit off - you need to, among other things, escape the brackets, like so:

```
/(\[\[[A-Za-z0-9\s]+\]\])/
```

...which will look for [[some text including whitespace]]

Adjust the group as desired.